# Python where do I run this from?

Tags: python, configuration, package

I'm trying to use clarifai with python, I've installed the package using pip, but then it says ([here](https://github.com/clarifai/clarifai-python)) to get started by configuration as follows.

---

Configuration

The client uses CLARIFAI_APP_ID and CLARIFAI_APP_SECRET for authentication and token generation. You can get those values from https://developer.clarifai.com and then **run**:

```
$ clarifai config
CLARIFAI_APP_ID: []: ************************************YQEd
CLARIFAI_APP_SECRET: []: ************************************gCqT
```

The config will be stored under ~/.clarifai/config for client's use

---

But I do not understand where I "run" this from and do i need the "$". I've tried running it from python command prompt and windows command terminal but it just gives errors.

I have a Python27/scripts folder, in this I have a file caled 'clarifai' but with unknow extension i.e. I dont know if its a .py file or .exe file, I have no idea. If I open that file in notepad it reads

```
""" the clarifai command line utility, 
Basically it helps to setup the environmental variables for the 
API Clients       """
```

So this is exactly what I want to do set the 'environmental variables' CLARIFAI_APP_ID: and CLARIFAI_APP_SECRET: but i have no idea how to do this. I tried to run this in the windows command terminal and in the python terminal but get errors both times.

someone suggested below "You should probably run in the folder you installed it to". But I did not install this, pip installed this I I dont understand where it installed it to?

Where should do you think they are implying I run this from?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `$`. You should probably run in the folder you installed it to, provided you didn't add to %PATH% yet. If you did, anywhere should be fine. Windows CMD or PowerShell is probably what they want.

Comment: but what folder did i install it in? I just use the pip install commmand, where does that install it? I have a python27 folder but nowhere do i see the .clarifai folder

Comment: I believe pip installs scripts into a subdirectory named Scripts inside the directory where Python is installed (on Windows). This is probably what needs to be added to %PATH%, assuming that is the problem.

Comment: I believe python, by default adds it to %PATH%. If not, you can add it by searching 'System Environment Variables` and adding it to your system or user PATH variable.

(On windows)

Comment: I do not understand any of this

Comment: I have a Python27/scripts folder, in this I have a file caled 'clarifai' but with unknow extension i.e. I dont know if its a .py file or .exe file. I have no idea. If I open that file in notepad it reads """ the clarifai command line utility, Basically it helps to setup the environmental variables for the API Clients """ So this is exactly what I want to do set the 'environmental variables' CLARIFAI_APP_ID: and CLARIFAI_APP_SECRET: but i have no idea how to do this. I tried to run this in the windows command terminal and in the python terminal but get errors both times.

Comment: open start, then type in "Edit the System Environment Variables". Click it. In the window that pops up, click "Environment Variables...". In that, there are 2 panes. In the 'System Variables' pane, click the Path variable twice, and a new window should pop up. Click new. Type in C:\Python27\Scripts or whereever your python is installed.

This should make PIP installed files run. Now you can run the thing that the documentation told you to.

Comment: Yes I know about "Edit the System Environment Variables" when i set up python I went in and added C:\Python27\Scripts. But I just dont understand how I run the above? If I go to windows command terminal and change directory to C:\Python27\Scripts then try and run the above code I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". if I try at the default command prompt i get the same error

Comment: Invalid syntax? That means the script you downloaded was wrong. Ask the creator of the script.